# Return data via echo from AJAX in PHP

Tags: php, ajax, json

I have just started coding in PHP. I previously worked in asp.net. In do net `webmethod` you return the data neatly to AJAX call. Trying in PHP I found that you at best can just `echo` the data you want to return.

If I convert the data to JSON on server and then return then it not sure PHP will not encode the error messages into it. That creates invalid JSON in client side code and the results are not possible to parse.

So I want to know if there is something advanced I can do to always return neatly and nicely from the server, even when an error occurs?

Clarification: first when error occurs then decoding on the client from JSON is not possible. This is the question, actually.

Comment: whats wrong with my question??

Comment: @Cristik is that not clear I want to return json data.. and when the error occur in php then you are in trouble because the error interferes with the endcoding of json. I think my question is pretty clear...

Comment: If you receive an error on the server, you need to catch that and return a JSON response that describes the error situation in an appropriate way for your application. What is appropriate here depends on what your error is and how you wish your application to handle it. What is the actual error you are experiencing?

Comment: @halfer Thanks for halving my question.. :) ... that is the answer I think.. I should handle the error on the server properly.. Thanks.. you can put that as answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the basis of this problem is an unhandled exception on the server, which will upset your JSON output with invalid strings (or, if error reporting is turned off as it should be, the JSON output will be unfinished, and thus still invalid).

Consider this AJAX code:

```
function getPost()
{
    return riskyOperation(); // throws \PDOException
}

echo json_encode(getPost());
```

That is obviously going to cause problems in the event of a database error. To fix it, you could do something like this:

```
function getPost()
{
    try
    {
        $post = riskyOperation(); // throws \PDOException
    }
    catch (\PDOException $e)
    {
        // @todo Log the exception here
        $post = ['error' => 'A database error occurred', ];
    }

    return $post;
}

echo json_encode(getPost());
```

Notice in this case I am not sending the error message to the client (in `$e->getMessage()`) since technical errors about the database are not appropriate for users, and may assist cracking attempts.

Also, it's worth programming defensively too - rather than running code that might throw an error, it is often possible to make checks prior to running that code, so that an error can be avoided instead of caught.

Comment: Now that is pretty cool!!!!! and my question need support. As it was not worthy to be downvoted.

Comment: @whatever, pleased this is of help. We tend to discourage asking for upvotes here - questions that are worthy of support will receive them in time. Perhaps a small code example may have helped clarify what you were looking for. I also edited out "please read the question carefully" as that might have got you even more downvotes. In short, don't worry about DVs, and just use them as encouragement to ask a more detailed question next time.

Comment: So sweet!!!! Thanks a lot!!! Not only stackoverflow but the whole world would be a nicer place if there were a few more humans like you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can echo the data in json data structure from php. Here is example

**PHP**

```
$data = array( 'name' => 'David' , 'age' => '25' );
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data); //Convert array to json string
```

**Javascript (Client Side)**

```
  var data = { 'var' : '123' }; // Some data if you want to send to server

    $.ajax({

    url: "PATH_TO_PHP_FILE", 
    data : data, 
    dataType: "json",

    success: function(json){

    var response=jQuery.parseJSON(json);

    if(typeof response =='object') {

    alert(json.name);
    alert(json.age);

    } else {        
    echo "Not valid json object";
    }

    }

    });
```

Comment: Now suppose you have run into error on the server.. then???

Comment: The server then will try to send you the error message and try to send that to the client and decoding on the client will then be messy..

Comment: Json data will be automatically decode in to the json object if you will add datatype: json, I will update the code above